# $L^1$-convergence implies $L^p$-convergence

Tags: real-analysis

If $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence in $L^1$ **and** in $L^p$ where $p>1$, also $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$, does that imply $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$ as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example, $\sqrt{n}\,\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$, but not in $L^2$.