# Example where convergence in mean does not imply convergence in quadratic mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is there an example where convergence in mean does not imply convergence in quadratic mean. $E|X_n-X|\rightarrow 0$ but $E|X_n-X|^2 \nrightarrow 0$.  It seems like this should be fairly straightforward, but I cannot really come up with an answer.  I'd imagine the answer would look something like

$$X_n=\begin{cases}a & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{n} \\\
 0& \text{with probability } 1-\frac{1}{n} \end{cases}$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/782558/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure let $X_n=\sqrt {n} I_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$. Then $E|X_n-0|\to 0$ but $E|X_n-0|^{2}=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: $E|X_n-0|^{2}=EnI_{(0,\frac  1 n)}=n \frac  1n =1$. @DemetriosPapakostas